# Span class within divs to separate 2 words html

Tags: html, css

Hi I'm trying to separate 2 words from each other by using a span but it does not seem to work. Not sure if it's because it's within a div.

```
.500{
display:inline-block;
margin-left:300px;
}

<div id="search"> 
<h2>
Search</h2>
<br>

0  <span class="500"> 500 </span>
<br />
</div>
```

Comment: you class should start from letter - http://jsfiddle.net/5Y2Zn/

Comment: Yeah, give the class name at least one letter at the beginning

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use class names which are only numerical. The class name should start with a letter.

EDIT: Oh I see Elen commented the same way. Please try out her [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5Y2Zn/) and check out how to correct your code.

```
.l500 {
  display:inline-block;
  margin-left:300px;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Start your class name with a letter: 
http://jsfiddle.net/5Y2Zn/

```
.l500{
display:inline-block;
margin-left:300px;
}

<div id="search"> 
<h2>
Search</h2>
<br>

0  <span class="l500"> 500 </span>
<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Class Names should start with a letter.

```
.span_500{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:300px;
}

<div id="search"> 
<h2>
Search</h2>
<br>

0  <span class="span_500"> 500 </span>
<br />
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

From the documentation [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-identifier)

> In CSS, identifiers (including element names, classes, and IDs in
>   selectors) can contain only the characters [a-zA-Z0-9] and ISO 10646
>   characters U+00A0 and higher, plus the hyphen (-) and the underscore
>   (_); **they cannot start with a digit**, two hyphens, or a hyphen followed
>   by a digit. Identifiers can also contain escaped characters and any
>   ISO 10646 character as a numeric code (see next item). For instance,
>   the identifier "B&W?" may be written as "B\&W\?" or "B\26 W\3F".

If for some crazy reason you need to do it -- you *could* (not recommended) access it like this:

```
span[class="500"] {
    display:inline-block;
    margin-left:300px;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/brbcoding/ssrzg/)**

Answer (score 0):

Do you just want a space between 0 and 500?

Put `&nbsp;`

Comment: It's a very bad way to separate words. Please read about spanning and margins in HTML/CSS